# PhpStorm. Не работает кнопка Submit

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

Есть два файла.
Первый

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            .bottom_block
            {
                background-color: white;
                <!--border: 1px black solid;-->
                border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

                width: 20vw;
                height: 20vh;
                margin-left: 39.5vw;
                margin-top: 2px;
            }
        </style>
    </HEAD>

       <div class="bottom_block">
        <FORM method="post" action="admin_authentication.php">
            <div style="width: 90%; height: 15%; margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 5%">
                <input type="text" style="width: 70%; height: 77%" placeholder="Username" name="admin_username" required>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 90%; height: 15%; margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 5%">
                <input type="password" style="width: 70%; height: 77%;" placeholder="Password" name="admin_password" required>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" name='admin_send' style="width: 40%; height: 100%" value="Submit">
            </div>

        </FORM>
    </div>
</HTML>
```

И второй admin_authentication.php

```
<?php
   echo $_POST['admin_username'];
   echo "Yes";
?>
```

когда этот код работает через "простой" (т.е. установленный на комп) apache, то он выдает и `$_POST['admin_username']` и слово `Yes`. Но когда его я запускаю из PhpStorm он выдает только `Yes` от чего это может быть???

Comment: Для начала, нужно привести разметку в валидное состояние. 99% что после этого проблема исчезнет.

Comment: простите а что за валидное состояние???

Comment: Иными словами, вам нужно привести разметку в соответствие со стандартом HTML. А вот вам и инструмент в помощь https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Начните с пропущенного тега `body` ;)

Comment: простите можно такой вопрос? а почему при выполнения кода не в PhpStorm работает он видит и `admin_username` и `admin_password`?

Comment: Зависит от браузера. В общем случае невалидная разметка может работать "как попало".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ответ на мой вопрос. После долгого поиска в инете нашел.

> Потому что у Вас по умолчанию, создаются две среды разработки, одна Ваша LAMP (mysite.com), вторая сам PHPStorm (localhost:port/projectfolder/). Хотите избавиться от этого, укажите в настройках проекта корректное имя домена. С готовым проектом делается так:
>
> Открыли проект
>
> 1)File->New project from existing files
>
> 2)Далее выбираем папку проект
>
> 3)После чего указываем доменное имя

[Источник](http://hostciti.net/faq/html/ne-rabotaet-obrabotchik-formi-v-phpstorm.html)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/171809)

Comment: полностью согласен с вами